# SQLite 3 , duplicate a row and change only one field

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I have some table in my SQLite3 database , for example

- table1
- table2
- table3

All tables have a field called id (integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE) (**not auto increment**)

My goal is to duplicate a record of one of these tables, changing only the id field (with a new id). I would like to do this without having to know the name of all the columns in each table.

I tried this solution, it works, but in this way i have to know the names of all columns

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id,column1,column2,column3)
SELECT NEWID,column1,column2,column3 FROM table1
WHERE id = OLDID
```

I tried also the method to create a temporary table, but without success

I have to run a query like this `PRAGMA table_info(table1)` , save the columns's name in an array , and then run a query created with a cycle ?

thanks

---

My solution

```
$TABLENAME = "mytablename";
$ID = 1423659222480;
$NEWID = 1423659222481;

$db = new PDO('sqlite:db.sqlite3');

$result_columns = $db->query("PRAGMA table_info(".$TABLENAME.")");
$appColumns = array();
$appColumns2 = array();
foreach ($result_columns as $row) {
    array_push($appColumns, $row["name"]); 
    if($row["name"] != "id") array_push($appColumns2, $row["name"]);
}

$appColumns = implode(",",$appColumns);
$appColumns2 = implode(",",$appColumns2);
$appColumnsWithoutID = $NEWID.",".$appColumns2;

$queryDuplicate = "INSERT INTO ".$TABLENAME." (".$appColumns.") SELECT ".$appColumnsWithoutID." FROM ".$TABLENAME." WHERE id = ".$ID;
```

Comment: Are the `id`s declare to be `auto_increment`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff , no ! INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE

Comment: I think you need dynamic SQL to do this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What do you think of my solution?

Comment: . . If it works, that is basically what needs to be done.